# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization:

Tags: java, swing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am getting this error when I try to mock `JTextField`.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable
    initialization: when resolving method
    "javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$1.dropLocationForPoint(
    Ljavax/swing/text/JTextComponent;Ljava/awt/Point;)Ljavax/
    swing/TransferHandler$DropLocation;" the class loader (instance of
    org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current
    class, javax/swing/text/JTextComponent$1, and the class loader
    (instance of <bootloader>) for interface
    sun/swing/SwingAccessor$JTextComponentAccessor have different Class
    objects for the type mponent$1.dropLocationForPoint(Ljavax/swing/text/
    JTextComponent;Ljava/awt/Point;)Ljavax/swing/TransferHandler$
    DropLocation; used in the signature
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:43)
```

I tried to use this:

```
@PowerMockIgnore( {"javax.management.*","javax.security.*","javax.ws.*"})
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: What are you mocking that is throwing this error? Assuming you had powermockito running before adding this, try commenting out the new code line by line, until you know whats causing this problem.

Comment: Try adding "java.swing.text.*" To your ignore list.

Comment: That didn't work.Mocking JTextArea is causing this issue.

Comment: What was your error message before you included @powerMockIgnore?

Comment: same linkage error as it is after adding PowerMockIgnore

Comment: I had a very similar problem but it was from something I wasn't mocking, I ended up having to mock it to get rid of the linkage error. Would you mind sharing the code you are using to mock JText field?

Comment: Just create a class with just one line e.g.. JTextArea text = new JTextArea(5,5); And write a test case .you can see for yourself.you can also check this issue was raised by another one here https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the scenario of the [cited issue](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/453) I have come with a workaround: the problem occurs in the static initializer of `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent` so we might *suppress* that code using `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("javax.swing.text.JTextComponent")`.

Here is a working test case (using Powermock 1.6.4):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(JOptionPane.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("javax.swing.text.JTextComponent")
public class PowerMockIssue {
    @Test
    public void powermockTest() {
        final JTextArea textArea = mock(JTextArea.class);
        when(textArea.getText()).thenReturn("test");
        Assert.assertEquals("test", textArea.getText());
    }
}
```